# error reference not defined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get error referenceerror:usd is not defined. CURRDEF=USD, what is suppose to do is 
user chooses sales center from dropdown and it will change the currency depending on 
what it is. i would think here is not passing it. not sure what im doing wrong.
on firebug it shows.

```
******************************************* 
CURRDEF := get_criteria_rec('PROP_CURR_DEF',dml_p_oracle_user.get_rec(VUSERNAME).global_region).include_list;


HTP.P( '<script> 
  function makeRequest(){
    var v_data_sales ={pvCurrCd:'||CURRDEF||',
                       pnSalesCenterID: $(this).find("#pnSalesCenterID").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url:contr_entry_pkg.select_sales_center,
        data:v_data_sales,
        async:false,
        success: function(vRetVal){
            var jsonObj =  eval("("+vRetVal+")");
        }

    });
};');
HTP.P( '</script>');        
     --------------

HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Currency:</td>');
HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');
HTP.P(Get_Currency_Dd(PVNAME=>'pvCurrCd', PVDEFVAL => NULL, PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1" onblur="makeRequest();"  style="width:200px"'));
HTP.P('</td>');
```

Comment: The main problem is likely right here: `var v_data_sales ={pvCurrCd:USD,` the `USD` var isn't defined. I'd expect mroe errors to occur though if that's all javascript... looks a little foreign to me.

Comment: yeah, but how do i define it , that is suppose to get it from a dropdown and change currency

Comment: Where is the dropdown? you can define a var with `var USD = "somevalue"`

Comment: HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Currency:</td>');
        HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');
         HTP.P(Get_Currency_Dd(PVNAME=>'pvCurrCd', PVDEFVAL => NULL, PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1" onblur="makeRequest();"  style="width:200px"'));
       HTP.P('</td>');

Comment: that doesn't look like a dropdown to me, i don't know what that is.

Comment: Instead of showing us the code that generates the javascript, show us the actual javascript. Even better, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: its a dropdown, if you know plsql

Answer (score 0):

I guess `USD` is not a variable. You must correct your script like:

```
var v_data_sales ={pvCurrCd:'USD' .
```

Or if you have this variable you must show us more code.

Comment: HTP.P('<td class="reqlabel1">Currency:</td>');
        HTP.P('<td class="tablelabel">');
         HTP.P(Get_Currency_Dd(PVNAME=>'pvCurrCd', PVDEFVAL => NULL, PVEVENT=>'class="reqinput1" onblur="makeRequest();"  style="width:200px"'));
       HTP.P('</td>');

Comment: are you asking for the whole thing , then no, its 1000 lines

Comment: So i guess we couldn't help you.

Comment: The best way to diagnose a problem like this is to find a minimal test case which demonstrates the problem. It will be easier for us to help you, clarify your thinking and (more often than not) identify the problem. I'm not trying to say "solve it yourself" merely that not all of those thousands of lines of code are problematic. Create a page which has nothing but your dropdown and a minimal amount of code to power it, then see if the problem still occurs. If not, add features back in until it breaks. If it's still broken, post the minimal page as a jsfiddle and we can probably help. Good luck